# How many spells should I give to a 1st level mage with intelligence 17?

Tags: spells, character-creation, adnd-2e

It's been 35+/- years since I've played, and I am DMing a new campaign. I'm having trouble figuring out how many spells a 1st level mage PC with an intelligence of 17 knows at the start of their career.

I'm using AD&D 2nd edition from the mid 80's.

Comment: Are you the DM or the Player Character?

Comment: Whoa people. Chill. Comments are not for trying to upsell askers on a later edition.

Comment: I am the DM..I played the original ADnD back in 84'-88'. I came across a small fortune in books from the 2nd edition. My teens wanted to play after hearing about all my misguided adventures from my storytelling days. I was able to pick up: 2DMG-2PG-monster compendium 1-3 & forgotten realms compendium. Character sheet book, thieves guild, mountainering guild, catacombs, dungeons, arcane alchemy, 3-4 others I can't remember.  This all came with 40+ issues of dungeon magazine and around 90+ issues of Dragon magazine.oh,  and I also got the temple of evil campaign complete with MAP booklet!

Comment: Sounds like a fun hoard! Enjoy, and we-all're here if/when you come up with other questions. Either mainsite (here) or just pop by [chat] and let us know how it's going.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The DM decides how many and which spells a 1st-level Wizard (Mage) gets.

From PHB2e (1989 printing), p.141, "Learning Spells":

> Whether a character chooses to be a mage or a specialist in one of the schools of magic, he must learn his spells from somewhere....
>
> Whatever the case, **your character begins play with a spell book containing up to a few 1st-level spells. Your DM will tell you the exact number of spells and which spells they are.**

You then to proceed to learn spells as you encounter them, as described in the Wizard (Mage) class description, subject to the "chance to learn" of 75% granted by your Intelligence.

### So how do I, the DM, choose?

The DMG, at p.41 has some suggested methods:

- The player names a spell, you roll against "chance to learn," repeat until you've hit max spells.<sup>*</sup>
- You assign the player *read magic, detect magic*, and four other spells you choose.
- The player gets 3d4 spells, two of which are *read magic* and *detect magic*. All others chosen according to one of the schemes above, or randomly, or however else you'd like to devise a spell-choice method.

### This is a matter of balance:

The designers were trying to balance *playability* versus *verisimilitude*. On the playability front one might like a player to be able to start with the spells they want. On the verisimilitude front they're trying to simulate what one would come out of "basic wizard training" with.

I, personally, like giving the player more agency at this point. Remember: for the rest of the character's life they will only be exposed to such spells as you place in their environment. But I also liked having them roll against "chance to learn," as that's a mechanic they'll need to come to terms with.

---

<sup>* - For your intelligence this would be 14 1st-level spells.</sup>

Comment: Okay,  then my math is correct. I wasn't sure if the pc would have gained any higher lvl spells. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Per the PHB quote it'd just be 1st-level spells in the book. On the other hand, you're free to sprinkle in whatever you'd like. Two very famous wizards--[Raistlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raistlin_Majere) and [Rincewind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rincewind)--have had story-worthy experiences with magic-beyond-their-level =)